# Word:mac 2011 preserve table formatting on copy-paste

Tags: macos, ms-office

In Microsoft Word 2010 for Windows, I can duplicate a table simply by clicking its handle at the top-left (which selects the entire table), copying it and pasting it. When I do that in Word:mac, the table and contents is duplicated without any of the table formatting. This kinda sucks because the original table has a number of merged cells and all sorts of formatting going on. I'm basically using the source table as a template.

I just updated Office:mac 2011 to SP2.

Answer (score 3):

Go to:

1. Word → Preferences → Edit → Settings 
    (under cut and paste options use smart cut and paste)
2. Remove the check mark on *"Adjust table formatting and alignment on paste"*.

Now try copy-paste of a table. It works.

Comment: I disabled "Use smart cut and paste" (Word -> Preferences -> Edit) and now it works. It should be called stupid cut and paste.

Comment: Neither of these tips worked for me. Using version "Word 2011 14.4.4. (14087)".

Answer (score 0):

Neither one of these methods works for me. I tried unchecking both boxes in the address mentioned, but the problem, yet remains. The table goes scattered after I try to paste it in Mac Pages.

Comment: This "Answer" is actually a question, not an answer. I understand that you do not have the rep required to leave comments, but a comment should never be posted as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

So I tried to copy a few lines of words with the table to paste and it worked. I hope it does for you too.

example: copy "Hello how are you" with "Table 3." and the table itself.

Hello how are you

Table 3.

Table here

Comment: The OP indicated above that disabling smart cut and paste solved the issue.